# Web scraping AJAX с сайта на Oracle Apex

Tags: python, ajax, парсер, requests, oracle-apex

Столкнулся с проблемой дублирования данных при парсинге.

С [сайта](https://115.xn--90ais/) на странице "Статистика" пытаюсь получить полный список районов для каждой области.

Последовательность моих действий/размышлений:

1. Понял, что данные подгружаются через wwv_flow.ajax

[image: Вводное сообщение с ChromeDevTools]

2. Для корректного получения параметров написал запрос вида. Для одного региона данный запрос отрабатывает корректно

```
import requests

headers = # передал данные для текущего файла из Request Headers 
data_params = # передал данные из Payload, кроме p_json
json_params = передал параметр p_json

url = "https://115.xn--90ais/portal/wwv_flow.ajax"

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers.update(headers)

    r = s.post(url=url, 
        data=data_params, 
        json=json_params, 
        )

    print(r.text)
```

3. Отследил, что при изменении области для каждой следующей меняется параметр P13_PROVINCE в Payload, внутри p_json. Ниже приведен список необходимых пар-ров для каждой области

```
province_dict = {
    'Minsk': '21',
    'Brest-obl': '41',
    'Vitebsk-obl': '78',
    'Gomel-obl': '124',
    'Grodno-obl': '170',
    'Mogilev-obl': '207',
    'Minsk-obl': '251',
}
```

4. Решил поместить все в цикле (пример кода ниже). На выходе получаю данные одной области, которые дублируются для остальных (ТУТ ВОЗНИКАЕТ ПРОБЛЕМА)

```
provinces = ['21', '41', '78', '124', '170', '207', '251']

url = ... # не изменяется
headers = ... # не изменяется
data = ... # не изменяется

for province in provinces:
    json_params = # ... itemsToSubmit": [{"n": "P13_PROVINCE", "v": province}], ...
    with requests.Session() as s:
        s.headers.update(headers)

        r = s.post(url=url, 
            data=data_params, 
            json=json_params, 
            )
```

Пример корректного результата, который хочу получить (для каждой из областей):

```
<option value="130">Брагинский район</option>
<option value="132">Буда-Кошелевский район</option>
<option value="134">Ветковский район</option>

...
```

Возможные проблемы, с которыми я мог не разобраться

- Корректные куки? В моем понимании, они должны быть одинаковы для каждого запроса. Этот параметр обязателен для корректного получения данных
- Параметры, содержащие в себе автогенерируемые (невычисляемые?) переменные (в Payload), типа: p_request: PLUGIN=..., в p_json: "salt": ..., "protected": ..., "p_instance": ... .Однако если изменять в одной и той же сессии области, то вроде как они константы.
- Данные генерируется при дополнительном действии со стороны пользователя js/ajax/... ?

Answer (score 0):

Пример post-запроса гомельская область.

```
data = {
    'p_flow_id': '10901',
    'p_flow_step_id': '13',
    'p_instance': '12770217650705',
    'p_debug': '',
    'p_request': 'PLUGIN=KjGlxkeewq44IZRW2bNB18qBKNfOcBeKyBU7k03J1GYbRokE4iXB-m8xS6TwClfh',
    'p_json': '{"pageItems":{"itemsToSubmit":[{"n":"P13_MONTH","v":"Четверг, 01 Сентябрь, 2022"},{"n":"P13_PROVINCE","v":"124"},{"n":"P13_DISTRICT","v":""}],"protected":"1cGOJtOJuelFSAeeh_y-bA","rowVersion":""},"salt":"184927490419308696276940592635347848743"}',
}
response = requests.post('https://115.xn--90ais/portal/wwv_flow.ajax', data=data)
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, что обратили внимание на вопрос. Да, для каждого отдельного запроса данные я получить могу, однако если это обернуть в цикл, где будет происходить итерация по {"n":"P13_PROVINCE","v":"124"}, ({"n":"P13_PROVINCE","v":"21 / 41 / 78 и т.д."},) то у меня на выходе дубликаты данных одной области для всех остальных